# Is it possible to have a coefficent of friction of zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I know that friction is determined by the equation $$F_f = \mu_fF_n ,$$ so technically if the normal force is $0$ then the force of friction will also be zero, but my question here is whether or not it is possible, or even exists, to have the coefficient of friction constant equal to $0$. If it is not possible then why not? And if it is possible, are there any current examples? This can apply to both kinetic and static friction.

Comment: Still in research, still controversial. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolid

Comment: Something supported by magnetic levitation is zero friction but there are electrical losses in the electrical conductors.  Yes mu can be zero in many physics questions, i.e. when they say the surface is frictionless.

Comment: @Alexander That should be an answer.

Comment: Why do you think a frictionless contact is not posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use superfluid helium under your bloc, and you should get $\mu = 0$.  The bloc could be made to inject liquid helium under its own base.

Answer (score 1):

The best real-world example of near-zero (but *not* zero) coefficient of friction is for the case of wet ice sliding on wet ice. For everyday materials, ice has the unusual property of melting under pressure. This means that when two blocks of ice are pressed together, the local contact points of highest pressure melt into water and the interface between them soon smooths itself down and becomes a thin layer of water at almost zero degrees C. The friction force that one block can exert on the other then is set by the viscosity of the water in the interface, which is low, and the blocks slide over each other with almost zero effort.

Relatively low friction is also got on an everyday basis with hydrodynamic bearings, in which a constant flow of lubricating oil is pumped into the small space between two parts that are rotating against each other- for example, the connecting rod that is clamped to the crankshaft in an automobile engine. In this case, the oil pressure "levitates" the two sliding surfaces out of contact with each other and both are then slipping on a thin layer of oil.

Teflon-on-teflon also creates a very low friction system if the teflon surfaces are sufficiently smooth. In this case, the intermolecular forces between a molecular strand of teflon on the surface of one block and another strand in the other are relatively weak and the two blocks "ignore" each other, allowing them to slip past one another with little friction.

Comment: I suppose there must be some sort of lubrication on the surfaces of the Teflon, because two perfectly smooth Teflon blocks in contact are just one block (as there’s no way for a molecule at the interface to know to which block it belongs)—the coefficient of friction is not zero, it’s infinite.

Comment: well, let me put "perfectly smooth" in quotes. In my own experience with machined blocks of teflon, they slip real good- but now I wonder if you could pressure-weld two blocks of it if they were atomistically smooth??

Answer (score 0):

Something supported by magnetic levitation is zero friction but there are electrical losses in the electrical conductors. Yes mu can be zero in many physics questions, i.e. when they say the surface is frictionless